# Layout issue after video reaches its end

Tags: trigger.io

Am having a layout issue after the video reaches its end, am using trigger.io.

Basically my play command is,

```
forge.media.videoPlay(url,
                function () {
                },
                function (error) {                        
                }
            );
```

The video plays nice, but after reaching its end and switching back to the page view, it does reload under the status bar.

Here is an example of what am taking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNL4K.jpg

This issue was tested on iOS 4.2.1

**Update #1:**

Body CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 320px;
    min-height: 460px;
    font-family: museo, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -o-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    font-smooth:auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Whats does your html, body css look like?

Comment: I need to spend some example time on this question over the weekend on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Are we speaking via email already? I've just sent you a reply :) Will post details as an answer here once we've made progress!

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any devices at 4.2.1, and aren't able to downgrade (thanks Apple!). Unfortunately, we haven't been able to recreate this on any of our devices or simulators, so my hunch is this is a bug in 4.2.1.

Comment: It could be but other apps for ex. Youtube doesn't show the same result. Weird!